# Advice about passing global data with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols

I've got an array of objects in ViewControllerA that need to be passed to ViewControllerE, which happens to be a view controller that is "several segues away." In other words, I cannot use a segue to pass my data. I've also tried using the protocol/delegate pattern, but realized that it's only for passing BACK data. In this case, I'm trying to pass FORWARD data.

Does anyone have advice on what I should do to get my data from VC-A to VC-E?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is already your answer, make it global, create a singleton class that hold the array of objects, then pass value to it and use it anywhere u want in your app

```
class Data {
    static let sharedData = Data()
    var array = [Object]()
}
```

In VC-A :

```
Data.sharedData.array = yourArray
```

Then retrieve it anywhere with `let array = Data.sharedData.array`

Comment: This feels so dirty though...Is it safe?

Comment: Well its the fastest and quickest way...I don't really see the reason for unsafe unless its jailbreak phone and u don't save it in your app documents/hard disk/etc..

Comment: Don't accept this answer, it's bad advice. Your data shouldn't be a singleton or global. It may be fast and quick but that doesn't make it the correct approach.

Comment: Can you point me towards a better direction? What's the appropriate measure?

Comment: After reading this, it seems like making my data global isn't too bad of a decision. It's really the only case in my app where I need to use a global. I know not to abuse this pattern, so I feel like it would be okay.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34475935/when-to-use-global-variables-in-swift

Comment: @rmaddy what would be a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Store in preference and use when needed. like that,

VC-A
let prefs: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
 prefs.setValue("YOURVALUE", forKey: "YOURKEYNAME")

VC-E
let prefs: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
prefs.valueForKey("YOURKEYNAME")

May be this is helpful. :)